# How to use inline-block

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some ads I want placing side by side and making all the same size but, whilst `float: left` works to get them to float left, `display: inline-block`, which should stack them in a grid side by side, and `max-width` doesn't.

Tried Css

```
@media (min-width: 768px){.box- 
layout {max-width: 100%; float: 
left; display: inline-block;}}
```

This, as mentioned, floats left but doesn't place side by side or make all the ads the same size. It also throws up a css lint obstruction that `float` and `display` can not be used together.

https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/

HTML:

```
<div class="line-layout" 
style="display: none;">
<li class="event_listing post-6985 
type-event_listing status-expired 
hentry" style="visibility: 
visible;" data-latitude="" data- 
longitude="">
<div class="event- 
info-row-listing">
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/
event/new-cross-and-deptford-free- 
film-festival/">
<div class="row"><div class="col- 
md-1">
<div class="organizer-logo">
<img alt="Deptford Film Festival" 
src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
content/uploads/event-manager-  
uploads/event_banner/2019/05/2
456d41f16399aed538d25b1cd32ad1
4.jpg">
</div>
</div><div class="col-md-4">
<div class="event-title">
<h4>New Cross and 
Deptford Free Film Festival</h4>
<div class="boxes-view- 
listing- 
registered-code">
</div>
<div class="event- 
organizer- 
name">
<normal>Deptford Film Festival
<normal></normal>
</normal>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="date" 
<date>2019-05-26</date>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="event- 
location"><i class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-map- 
marker"></i> London </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="event- 
ticket">#free</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</li>
</div>
<!-- Box Layout -->
<a class="event_listing post-6985 
type-event_listing status-expired 
hentry" href="https://adsler.co.uk
/event/new-cross-and-deptford-free- 
film-festival/">
<div class="box-layout">
<div class="event-img"><img 
alt="Deptford Film Festival" 
src="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
content/uploads/event-manager-  
uploads/event_banner/2019/05/2
456d41f16399aed538d25b1cd32
ad14.jpg"></div>
<div class="boxes-view-box- 
registered-code">
</div>
<div class="event-title">
New Cross and Deptford Free Film 
Festival
</div>
<div class="event-start- 
date">2019- 05-26
</div>
<div class="event-location">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
map- 
marker"></i> London </div>
<div class="box-footer">
<div class="event- 
ticket">#free</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: First I would start by fixing your invalid HTML. `<li>` is the only valid direct child of a `<ul>`, yet you have `<ul> -> <div> -> <li>` which is invalid. Also, you can use `float` and `display` together... every element has a display, so it would be impossible to not use `display` with `float`

Comment: your `.box-layout` elements are also not side-by-side...they are all nested inside `<a>` tags and those `<a>` tags are side by side.

Comment: Ok cool. Just repeating css lint error message so I've had to put in separate queries... Also, it's a plugin so difficult to modify html direct, particularly as id have to modify php which I don't know anything about. Is there an overriding css option please? Thanks.

Comment: So something like`.box-layout a {foo}`?

Comment: One of you main problems is that you have `.box-layout { width: 32% }` css style. But `.box-layout` is nested inside `<a>` tags. So you should remove that width on the `.box-layout` and put it on the `<a>` tag... i.e. `.entry-content a { width: 32%; }`

Comment: `@media (min-width: 768px){.entry-content a{width: 32%;}}` and `@media (min-width: 768px) {.box-layout {width: unset;}}`?

Comment: ya that looks right (or `width: auto;` instead of `unset`). does that get you closer to what you are after?

Comment: @zgood yes, almost perfect, brilliant. Now all i need are them to be the  same size and aligned.... see here desktop https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/

Answer (score 0):

your html and css are quite chaotic.
I made an example how it should be and how it works.
Ps. don't pay attention to

```
max-width:800px;
```

thats just for demo purposes.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXWLrg

Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Precisely. Thanks. But i can't edit html. If is use that css, will it work even if html isn't edited?

Comment: Basically, if you see the ad `horsens Medieval festival`i want the box layout to be like that for each one?

Comment: Looks like you're not making it easy to me? :D Doesn't feel good BUT just paste this css somewhere and it should make it a lot better. https://codepen.io/skeefee/pen/ZdEELw

Comment: :-) Thanks but all i need is a media query above 768px standardising height. width is correct and they are displaying correctly now apart from height....can't i do `height: foobar; `or something?